# Recursively remove all the numbers in the string and return reversed version of that string without numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I need to remove all the numbers from the string recursively and then return the reversed string.

```
def remove_numbers_and_reverse(string):

if string == "":
    return string
elif string[-1].isdigit():
    string.replace(string[-1], "")
return string[-1] + remove_numbers_and_reverse(string[:-1])
```

For example if the input is "bunny1234" then the output should be "ynnub". But i get "4321ynnub".

```
"bunny1234" -> "ynnub"
"3434string" -> "gnirts"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is the `elif`part: You are not doing anything with your replaced string, replace is not working in-place. So instead you might try this:

```
def remove_numbers_and_reverse(string):

    if string == "":
        return string
    elif string[-1].isdigit():
        return remove_numbers_and_reverse(string[:-1])
    else:
        return string[-1] + remove_numbers_and_reverse(string[:-1])


print(remove_numbers_and_reverse("bunny1234"))
print(remove_numbers_and_reverse("3434string"))
```

Here I just ignore the last character if it is a digit.
For shorter and smarter solutions see @Amolb's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Removing number try below approach:

**1. using join and isdigit**

```
ini_string = "Test123ing127you"
print("initial string : ", ini_string) 
res = ''.join([i for i in ini_string if not i.isdigit()]) 
print("final string : ", res)
```

**2. Using translate and digits**

```
from string import digits 
ini_string = "Test123ing127you"
remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits) 
res = ini_string.translate(remove_digits) 
# printing result 
print("final string : ", res)
```

**3. Using filter and lambda**

```
ini_string = "amol23bais"
res = "".join(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), ini_string)) 
# printing result 
print("final string : ", str(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have answered it but might as well throw in my example too.

```py
def remove_numbers_and_reverse(my_string):
  if not my_string:
    return my_string
  else:
    for letter in my_string:
      if letter.isdigit():
        continue
      output = letter + output
  return output
```

The output:

```py
[user@machine test-dir]$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Aug 15 2019, 16:59:35)
>>> import test
>>> test.remove_numbers_and_reverse("bunny1234")
'ynnub'
>>> test.remove_numbers_and_reverse("3434string")
'gnirts'
>>> test.remove_numbers_and_reverse("3434string123123morestring")
'gnirtseromgnirts'
>>> test.remove_numbers_and_reverse("")
''
>>>
```